# How to get byte array from input type file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I am generating my Html page from database (html tags are stored in database) using sql-server functions .. when generating controls I am easily able to deal with all type input controls but in case of input type "file" I am unable to get bytes of uploaded Image/File , i have a requirement of saving file/image byte into DB .
      Requirement -- How to get imagebytes from input type File using JavaScript , from onclick event of a input type button ...

Comment: Could you give an output of image from database? Here is a good article about image file inputs but I don't know, will it help in your case: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: I tried your given link but that not worked ...

Answer (score 22):

This took me 8 hours to figure out lol. Here you go :)

```
function submitForm() {
   var fileList = document.getElementById("image").files;
   var fileReader = new FileReader();
   if (fileReader && fileList && fileList.length) {
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileList[0]);
      fileReader.onload = function () {
         var imageData = fileReader.result;
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: how did you convert from ArrayBuffer to [] byte?

Comment: but the onload called after some time only